# How to encode and append ContentValue values into an URL

Tags: android, content-values

Earlier when `NameValuePairs` were available directly it was easy to encode and append URL variables using:

```
String UrlString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8");
```

But now they have been deprecated I moved onto using `ContentValues` for storing name-value pairs.

What I want to ask that is there an easy and straight way to encode and append ContentValue values into an URL like it was possible with  `NameValuePairs` or else how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to ask that is there an easy and straight way to encode and append ContentValue values into an URL like it was possible with  `NameValuePairs` or else how to do it?

If it's query parameters you're referring to, it's probably best to have a look at [`Uri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html). In particular, its [`Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html) provides various methods to set or append path segments, query parameters (either pre-encoded or not) and the like. Encoding values is also supported through the static `Uri.encode()` helpers.

That being said, if you need a simple drop-in replacement for the formatting options provided by `URLEncodedUtils`, it would be pretty straightforward to take its source code and make it compatible with `ContentValues` (or a `Map<String, Object>` for that matter, since `ContentValues` is little more than a thin wrapper around that).

I've set up a quick (and untested) [gist](https://gist.github.com/mhelder/2899ab96217a6795ceac) for this. Feel free to use it as a starting point, and - by all means - fix any mistakes I may have made.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building the URL via a String here's how to do that.

String urlEncoded = "http://google.com/search?q=" + Uri.encode(query);